# Windows Server 2012 R2, cannot install any role or features using GUI Server manager

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Exiting environment : Windows Server 2008 R2.
 I am in the process of migrating to Windows Server 2012 R2. I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 on HP DL380p G8 server. I am able to install role or feature using PowerShell but not via GUI ServerManager.

Now, when I go to add a any role or features using GUI ServerManager I am getting the following errors:

```
**Failed to open runspace pool. The Server Manager WinRM plug-in might be corrupt or missing**
```

I did the following troubleshooting already:

- Run WinRM quickconfig which shows the service is running and setup for management.
- Restored WinRM settings: winrm invoke restore winrm/config @{}
- Restored WinRM plugin settings: winrm invoke restore winrm/config/plugin @{}
- Add "127.0.0.1" and "::1" to the IP listen list
- Disabled the firewall
- Ensured the Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) service is running.
- Granted the  “Validated Write to Service Principal Name” permission to the NETWORK SERVICE using theADSIEDIT.msc

Following are the errors logged:
**Event ID 10154**

```
The WinrRM failed to create the following SPNs:WSMAN/xxx.abc.com:WSMAN/xxx
```

Application and services log
Event ID 142

```
WSMAN Operation CreateShell failed, error code 2150858811
```

I googled but nothing seems to help.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with the OS installation. If possible, I would run a sfc /scannow on the server and see if that corrects it. If not, toss the OS CD in there and run a repair from that.

Comment: I thought the same but I built a new server with new installation media and I am getting same error.

Comment: Did you install it from the same CD or a different CD?

Comment: I download a new ISO from MS Volume Licensing site and created a new installation media and ran setup.

Comment: Remote Shell Access was disabled via GPO. Once I disabled the GPO and I was able to install a role or features.

Comment: @prabsom Don't forget to add the answer and mark the question answered...Future admins may not notice your answer within the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use setspn to manually create the SPN
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348559%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

```
SETSPN -A WSMAN/{server-short-name}{domainshortname\server-short-name}
SETSPN -A WSMAN/{server-FQDN-name.}{domainshortname\server-short-name}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to a GPO setting in Windows Remote Management. As soon as you set the "Allow Remote Shell Access" to Not Configured it should work.
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Remote Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have duplicate SPNs.
if you want to use WSMAN AND kerberos SSO, you will need to use CNAMEs

**check for what user has the duplicate SPN**

```
setspn -Q WSMAN/xxx.abc.com
setspn -Q WSMAN/xxx
```

You'll need to delete them from that user and re-assign them to the computer account (with setpn).

**delete duplicate spn**

```
SetSpn -D domain/user WSMAN/xxx.abc.com
SetSpn -D domain/user WSMAN/xxx
```

**Reassign**

```
SetSpn -A WSMAN/xxx.abc.com
SetSpn -A WSMAN/xxx
```

You will also need to do this for `HTTP` where you want to use WinRM.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was because I had an IP binding on the command line, and the server then wasn't bound on the localhost. To overcome this, I added a binding to 127.0.0.1:

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1
net stop http /y
net start http
net start w3svc

Once I did this, I could then add Roles and Features using the GUI.

Credit here: http://www.lukebrowning.com/sysadmin/windows/windows-server-2012-winrm-corrupt-or-missing/

Answer (score -1):

I realize you found the solution, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this error: I am almost ashamed to suggest this, but here is the obvious thing to try before going on a wild goose chase: Reboot.

I was having the same problem, and after a couple of hours of banging my head against the wall, it occured to me to try and restart the server. That did the trick, and it sure made me feel stupid for wasting the afternoon troubleshooting. Seems that WinRM was in some kind of faulty state.