# WinRM issues using add/remove features using Server 2012 r2 Server Manager

Tags: winrm, window-server-2012

I am trying to get 2 servers to talk to each other through server manager both running Windows Server 2012 R2.

SERVER1 is able to refresh all the server information without a problem. I can see all the status of SERVER1 & 2 without a problem.
SERVER2 says that the RPC server is unavailable and that it cannot find SERVER 1.

When I do the following command `winrm id -r:SERVER2` from SERVER1 I get an error `80338126` mainly meaning it cannot sea SERVER2.

winrm quickconfig shows that it is setup and manageable on SERVER2. It is allowed through the firewall using GPO which is applied to both servers.

I have tried these fixes:
[Fix 1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/5a1be253-7d4c-4bed-8750-c6052d39b7c8/failed-to-open-the-runspace-pool-the-server-manager-winrm-plugin-might-be-corrupted-or-missing?forum=winserver8gen)
[Fix 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/733928/windows-server-2012-r2-cannot-install-any-role-or-features-using-gui-server-man)
[Fix 3](https://serverfault.com/questions/808879/the-server-manager-winrm-plug-in-might-be-corrupted-or-missing-on-w2k12r2)
[Fix 4](http://www.lukebrowning.com/sysadmin/windows/windows-server-2012-winrm-corrupt-or-missing/)

I have checked the following:

- System is listening on 127.0.0.1, Network IP Address, ::1
- WinRM is configured and is Remotely Manageable
- WinRM Enumerate is showing listening on Port 5296 and is allowed through firewall
- Remote Shell is set to Not Configured
- Server has been Restarted

Is there anything else I can do? WinRM should be working. This is a production server and is configured to run MULTIPLE things. I cannot rebuild it.

**UPDATE**: I found a firewall rule called "HTTP Through TLS/SSL" set to "public" instead of Private/Domain. I changed that. SERVER2 can not WinRM to SERVER1 but using the Server Manager I get this error:

> Configuration Refresh failed with the following errors. The metadata
>   failed to be retrieved from the server do to the following error. The
>   WS-Management service cannot process the request. The resource URI was
>   not found in the catalog. The catalog contains the metadata that
>   describes resources or logical endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following key was missing from the registry.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Service]
"allow_remote_requests"=dword:00000001
```

Added the key and restarted the Windows Remote Management service and SERVER1 can now refresh status with SERVER2.

Did a quick check on the Listener for WinRM and found it was listening through port 5296 but had no firewall rule to allow it through. Made a firewall rules and now both servers are talking.

To check your WinRM comms go to CMD and run the following commands.

```
winrm qc
winrm e winrm/config/listener
```

Answer (score 0):

> Open NotePad/IDE and copy the script below. Save the WMI script text file as "reinstall-wmi.bat" Double-click the .bat batch file to execute the script. Then restart the server for the configurations to take place.

```
@echo on

cd /d c:\temp

if not exist %windir%\system32\wbem goto TryInstall

cd /d %windir%\system32\wbem

net stop winmgmt

winmgmt /kill

if exist Rep_bak rd Rep_bak /s /q

rename Repository Rep_bak

for %%i in (*.dll) do RegSvr32 -s %%i

for %%i in (*.exe) do call :FixSrv %%i

for %%i in (*.mof,*.mfl) do Mofcomp %%i

net start winmgmt

goto End


:FixSrv

if /I (%1) == (wbemcntl.exe) goto SkipSrv

if /I (%1) == (wbemtest.exe) goto SkipSrv

if /I (%1) == (mofcomp.exe) goto SkipSrv

%1 /RegServer


:SkipSrv

goto End## Heading ##


:TryInstall

if not exist wmicore.exe goto End

wmicore /s

net start winmgmt

:End
```

CREDIT   http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-2008-setup-windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-service-failed.aspx

Comment: Did you intentionally mess up the formatting?

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault.  Please try to edit your post and use the editing tools to format your batch file so that we can read and understand it.  Also an explanation of how it addresses the problem would be helpful as well.